# Is there a better way to print hex to file?

Tags: c, binary, hex

I'm trying to transform binary to hex format, the binary data is a flow comes in every second,and my code is as follow:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
{
   sprintf(in+i*2, "%02x", s[i]);
}
fprintf(fp, "%s\n", in);
```

but it's too slow cause the data comes in so quickly.

Is there a better way to handle it?

Is there any function like fnprintf(fp, size, "%.*02x\n", num, in)?

Comment: I think that you may be over-thinking this. You are able to get the spacing write in printing to a string with plain ol' `sprintf`, so why do you think you'd have a harder time printing directly to the file with `fprintf`?

Comment: it's a part of ulogd plugin, and I need to log the data to a file for later process. And the problem is that it's too slow to convert the binary data to hex format.

Comment: Then you should think carefully about the place that `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)` has in your loop. I mean, you can hope that the compiler can tell that it can pull the `strlen` call out, but that requires a fairly smart optimizer. Maybe it's time to profile?

Comment: The see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html and  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html .

Comment: You appear to be treating `s` as both a string and a binary stream.  Presumably zero is not a valid data value in the stream, or is at least the message terminator?

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that you are calling `strlen` on every pass of the loop.  Note that `strlen` has to count bytes until it finds the end of the string.  If your string is 100 bytes long, then the loop will call `strlen` 100 times, and each time `strlen` will count through 100 bytes. The result is that `strlen` will end up counting a total of 10000 bytes before the loop ends.

The second problem is that you're calling `sprintf` on every pass through the loop.  All of the members of the `printf` family are fairly heavy-weight functions, and should be avoided in high performance code.  Given that it's easy to convert a byte into a two digit hex number, you don't really need the `sprintf`.

So here's what the code looks like if you eliminate the `strlen` and the `sprintf`.  (I've also thrown in some security, by checking for output buffer overflow. That's what `bend` is being used for.)

```
#define BUFSIZE 200

int digit;
char *sptr, *bptr, *bend;
char string[BUFSIZE];
char buffer[BUFSIZE];

bptr = buffer;
bend = &buffer[BUFSIZE - 2];
for ( sptr = string; *sptr != '\0'; sptr++ )
{
    digit = (*sptr >> 4) & 0xf;
    *bptr++ = ( digit > 9 ) ? digit + 'a' - 10 : digit + '0';

    digit = *sptr & 0xf;
    *bptr++ = ( digit > 9 ) ? digit + 'a' - 10 : digit + '0';

    if ( bptr >= bend )
        break;
}
*bptr = '\0';

fprintf( fp, "%s\n", buffer );
```

Comment: Thanks!  Using your approach, the performance increased several times.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Stop using `strlen()` in your loop conditional. It is feasible the compiler will realize its value is constant and optimize the repetition away, but why rely on that when you need not use it in the first place?
2. Stop using such expensive functionality for what is arguable a trivial task. All you care about is putting out the character digits of the two nibbles in each byte, so *do that*:

You will be hard-pressed to beat the performance of a simple lookup sequence with the potentially-macro-version of `fputc`. It is likely you will be at or near epsilon overhead when dumping to a buffered io stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void hex_dump(FILE *fp, const void *src, size_t slen)
{
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    const unsigned char *p = src;
    while (slen--)
    {
        putc(digits[(*p >> 4) & 0xF], fp);
        putc(digits[*p++ & 0xF], fp);
    }
    putc('\n', fp);
}


int main()
{
    const char msg[] = "A simple message to print";
    hex_dump(stdout, msg, sizeof(msg));
}
```

**Output**

```
412073696d706c65206d65737361676520746f207072696e7400
```

Note: My choice of [`putc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc) is intentional. It can be (and frequently is) a macro that directly mucks with the buffering of the `FILE` stream. Reason: Faaaast.

Of course you can front the above with a simple `strlen` forwarder. Such as:

```
void hex_dump_str(const char *s)
{
    hex_dump(s, strlen(s));
}
```

Or customize it entirely to terminate on the nulchar and eliminate the `strlen` scan, as you can do it while you're actually dumping to the stream. The choice is yours. Something like:

```
void hex_dump_str(FILE *fp, const char *src)
{
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char*)src;
    while (*p)
    {
        putc(digits[(*p >> 4) & 0xF], fp);
        putc(digits[*p++ & 0xF], fp);
    }
    putc('\n', fp);
}
```

Best of luck.